# Do an operation for every row in df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I want to subtract for every row 360 if the number in the cell is bigger than 720 and smaller than 1080. How can I do the if statement for every row in my df?

I tried this:

```
if row in (df['position']>720 and df['position']<1080):
   df['720-1080']=(df['position']-360)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with mask by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'position':[7000,800,1000]})

mask = df['position'].between(720, 1080, inclusive=False)
#alternative
#mask =  (df['position']>720) & (df['position']<1080)
df['720-1080'] = df['position'].mask(mask, df['position'] - 360)
print (df)
   position  720-1080
0      7000      7000
1       800       440
2      1000       640
```

Comment: can I do it multiple times? I need to subtract or add 360 up to 3 times. So that every value is between 0 an 360 degrees in the end. My plan was to expand the if with several elif.

Comment: get stil a `nan` even if the position is bigger than 720. It also would be great if iget insetad of a `nan` just the number without subtract 360 if the number is smaller than 720.

Comment: but it doesn't work for between 360 an 720. But the easiest way for me would be: if the number is greater than 720 subtract 360 else takte the number without subtraction.

Comment: ok sorry, maybe I am just very stupid... but I tried this: `mask = df['position'].astype(float).between(720, 1080, inclusive=False) 
df['720-1080'] = df['position'].mask(mask, 360)` If I do this it just takes the number from position without any substraction

Comment: @1lk4 - No, it was my first wrong code, now use `df['720-1080'] = df['position'].mask(mask, df['position'] - 360)`